# real quadratic factor with complex conjugate roots

Tags: polynomials

I am doing a school assignment, and it said; "There are several other possible combinations of factors for a quartic polynomial. Continue your investigation into at least two of these other possibilities, including a polynomial having a real quadratic factor with complex conjugate roots." What does it mean? Could you please give me an example of the equation? (I am really struggling with this, so I really need help with this)

Answer (score 0):

They're asking you to factor the quartic into two quadratics so that at least one of the quadratics doesn't split further over the real numbers (hence, its factors are complex functions).

Comment: what does that mean tho? Could you please provide an example please...

Comment: @Austin Exactly what is unclear that you want an example of?